# Pass variables from element to view in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a bulky array that is used in several views so I store it in an element file and fetch it when needed:

`element/select.ctp`:

```
$districts = array(
    __('Region A') => array(
        __('district 1') => __('district 1'),
        __('district 2') => __('district 1'),
        __('district 3') => __('district 1')
    ),
    __('Region B') => array(
        __('district 4') => __('district 4'),
        __('district 5') => __('district 5'),
        __('district 6') => __('district 6')
    )
);
```

And I include it in `profiles/add.ctp`:

```
echo $this->element('select');
echo $this->Form->Create('Profile');
echo $this->Form->input('district', array(
    'options' => $districts
);
```

But the variable isn't passed. I wonder how I can pass it from the element?

Comment: can you try to return the ``$distrincts``

Comment: I print_r it in the view and it returns error stating its an undefined variable

Comment: Don't set variables in the View templates. Use you're controllers for this. See Lars Ebert's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements are not the right way to do this. Elements are used to render or display similar snippets multiple times in multiple views. You can pass variables from the View to the Element, but not the other way around.

I would recommend putting the array into your AppController like this:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Controller;

    use Cake\Controller\Controller;
    use Cake\Event\Event;

    class AppController extends Controller
    {
        public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
            $this->set('districts', array(
                __('Region A') => array(
                    __('district 1') => __('district 1'),
                    __('district 2') => __('district 1'),
                    __('district 3') => __('district 1')
                ),
                __('Region B') => array(
                    __('district 4') => __('district 4'),
                    __('district 5') => __('district 5'),
                    __('district 6') => __('district 6')
                )
            ));
        }
    }

?>
```

This way, every view will have the variable `$districts` filled with the array.

If you need to do this on a per action basis, you can do this in your AppController:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Controller;

    use Cake\Controller\Controller;
    use Cake\Event\Event;

    class AppController extends Controller
    {
        public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
            $this->districts = array(
                __('Region A') => array(
                    __('district 1') => __('district 1'),
                    __('district 2') => __('district 1'),
                    __('district 3') => __('district 1')
                ),
                __('Region B') => array(
                    __('district 4') => __('district 4'),
                    __('district 5') => __('district 5'),
                    __('district 6') => __('district 6')
                )
            );
        }
    }

?>
```

And then pass the array to every view you need it in your Controllers:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Controller;

    class SomeController extends AppController
    {
        public function index() {
            $this->set('districts', $this->districts);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. would it cause less workload or more if I create a middle layer of class between AppController and, say, ProfileController to store the array?

Comment: As there are only certain controllers that will need the variables.

Comment: I see no problem with creating a class between the AppController and the ProfileController, as long as the between-Controller still inherits the AppController. Also make sure that the betweenControllers beforeFilter method calls the AppController beforeFilter method with `parent::beforeFilter($event);` at the beginning of the beforeFilter method.